# node_load(): correct syntax for this use-case

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using node_load to load a node based on the value of one of its fields. If the field I'm testing against were `uid` for example, I would do it like this:

```
$n1 = node_load(array('uid' => $val));
```

but this field `sub1` is nested in an array `field_val[0][sub1]`. I tried putting quotes around the whole thing, but it didn't work. I tried other small variations, but none worked.

```
$n1 = node_load(array('field_val[0][sub1]' => $val));
```

I'm wondering what's the correct syntax for doing this, if it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument taken from `node_load()` is

- An array following the format `<table field> => <value>`.
- The node ID.

In the first case the array index is the name of a field found in the table node.

It's not possible to call `node_load()` as you reported.